# Guide for constructing the private blockchain network using Aptos

Tags: blockchain, aptos

I try to construct a private blockchain network using Aptos.

Is there any guide to do this, such as [Private Networks document for Ethereum](https://geth.ethereum.org/docs/fundamentals/private-network).

I found ["Configuring your fullnode as a private fullnode" section in Full Node Network Connection page](https://aptos.dev/nodes/full-node/fullnode-network-connections#configuring-your-fullnode-as-a-private-fullnode), but I'm not sure this is what I want.

If you have any good guide for constructing the private network using Aptos, please recommend them. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to run a localnet for your own development, you can do

```bash
aptos node run-local-testnet --force-restart
```

But if you are asking how to run a POA chain, I don't think that's possible now without changing the code of node.